# Illegal 304 HTTP response?

Tags: c#, image, google-chrome

So this is an interesting problem and I'm not sure even where to start looking on this one. I have an MVC3 application written in C# that lists online advertisements. On the home page, it displays a list of the 10 most recent ads that have been placed with photos. Take a look at [this page](http://www.equispot.com/horses-for-sale/results/) in Chrome. On the first page load, it loads just fine. Now hit F5. It will continue to show the "loading" indicator in the browser tab and if you scroll down, 2 or 3 of the ad images don't show up. The odd thing is that it's always images in the same area of the page (maybe the 6th, 7th or 8th image). It's never the first few and its never the last ones.

This only happens in Chrome and only when you hit F5. If you click on the "Equispot" logo at the top (which redirects you to the home page) it works just fine.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this or how to troubleshoot this?

**EDIT**: I think I might be getting somewhere. Fiddler indicates a 500 error on the images that are not displaying. This is the error:

*[Fiddler] Response Header parsing failed.
This can be caused by an illegal HTTP response earlier on this reused server socket-- for instance, a HTTP/304 response which illegally contains a body.*

Since all my images are cached and there are several 304 responses prior to the missing images, this seems like a likely culprit. Not sure how to approach a fix though as this is unfamiliar territory for me.

Comment: It would be helpful @Scott if you were to acknowledge this question as answered so it doesn't keep popping up. Although admittedly, only 5 hours have elapsed. (Some people leave questions that were answered on their own or by others to languish for months, so I'm not truly griping). I enjoyed the horse pictures, and also learned something useful about re-used server sockets, for which I thank you.

Comment: I was waiting to be able to do that. You have to wait two days to mark your own answer as the correct one.

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize. Thanks for telling me about the two day rule. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. I had a FileCache attribute that was adding unnecessary bytes to the response for cached images. Removed that and the problem resolved itself and the controller is now returning 0 byte 304 responses.

Answer (score 0):

According to my Chrome's Network monitor, the problem seems to occur with access to **xd_proxy.php**, which on page-refresh, does not seem to return.

```
    {"pageref":"http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb=f2583cfee4&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.equispot.com%2Ff1f91777c&relation=parent.parent&transport=postmessage&type=resize&height=20&ackData[id]=1&width=90",
"startedDateTime":"2011-07 10T15:01:26.361Z",
"time":1,"request":
{"method":"GET","url":"http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb=f2583cfee4&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.equispot.com%2Ff1f91777c&relation=parent.parent&transport=postmessage&type=resize&height=20&ackData[id]=1&width=90",
"headers":[],
"queryString":[{"name":"version","value":"3#cb"},{"name":"origin","value":"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.equispot.com%2Ff1f91777c"},{"name":"relation","value":"parent.parent"},{"name":"transport","value":"postmessage"},{"name":"type","value":"resize"},{"name":"height","value":"20"},{"name":"ackData[id]","value":"1"},{"name":"width","value":"90"}],
"cookies":[],"headersSize":-1,"bodySize":-1},"response":{"status":0,"statusText":"","headers":[],"cookies":[],"content":{"size":2575,"mimeType":"text/html"},"redirectURL":"","headersSize":-1,"bodySize":2575},"cache":{},"timings":{"blocked":0,"dns":-1,"connect":-1,"send":-1,"wait":-1,"receive":0,"ssl":-1}}
```

Comment: I've seen it trying to keep loading from Facebook, Adsense, Analytics, etc. It seems random. If you go back to the page, and try it again, is it the same resource that won't load?

Comment: @Scott, so far it has been that but I admit I haven't checked the others as this one consistently stood out.  Interestingly enough, it was labelled as `(from cache)` each time.