# ASP.NET Web Api The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I am getting this error on random requests, from an ASP.NET Web Api webserver I control.

```
System.Net.WebException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
  Source=Microsoft.Threading.Tasks
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at DC.Dataloader.Api.BaseApi.<ExecuteWithErrorAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\WIL\DonorConnect\DC.Dataloader\Api\BaseApi.cs:line 63
  InnerException:
```

No exceptions are thrown (and/or caught) server side. Method signatures look like:

```
[Route("controller/method")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<SomeDto> method(string someParam, bool someFlag) {
```

Fiddler gives the following messages:

```
The Server did not return properly formatted HTTP Headers. HTTP headers
should be terminated with CRLFCRLF. These were terminated with LFLF.
```

---

```
Response does not start with HTTP. Data:

�����a]��+E�?<1C�9_3�(>�
```

---

```
[Fiddler] Response Header parsing failed.
This can be caused by an illegal HTTP response earlier on this reused server socket-- for instance, a HTTP/304 response which illegally contains a body.
Response Data:
<plaintext>
1F 8B 08 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 CC BD CB 72 23 49 96 25 F8 2B 94 DC F4 8C  .........Ì½Ër#I%ø+Üô
48 55 74 00 7C F7 0E 0F 3A E9 24 E0 CE 21 98 E1 12 35 8B 11 05 A0 04 34  HUt.|÷..:é$àÎ!á.5.. .4
69 30 65 29 CC C8 80 B7 CC A2 3F A7 17 B3 68 99 DD 6C 46 64 F2 C7 46 0D  i0e)ÌÈ·Ì¢?§.³hÝlFdòÇF.
EE 7C E0 AA F1 1E 03 EF 85 77 65 49 89 57 78 78 D1 4F 9A A9 5D BD AF 73  î|àªñ..ïweIWxxÑO©]½¯s
CE FF FE 5F FF 36 71 D3 BF FD 97 F6 BF FC 6D F2 7F 5C 07 7B E7 FE 6A FD  Îÿþ_ÿ6qÓ¿ýö¿ümò\.{çþjý
ED BF FC 6D 18 96 BF FD AD FA AD BB 2F 66 61 AB DF B9 36 45 E1 D6 BF B5  í¿üm.¿ý­ú­»/fa«ß¹6EáÖ¿µ
78 FE AD F5 3F 65 CF FF 34 70 B3 79 91 DB B0 FE DD 51 79 F7 F3 27 AD FF  xþ­õ?eÏÿ4p³yÛ°þÝQy÷ó'­ÿ
F1 C6 E6 4F 76 7C 6D C3 D2 E7 9F FB 7F FB 2F 79 99 65 FF F2 B7 99 CD A7  ñÆæOv|mÃÒçûû/yeÿò·Í§
F1 CF AF FF E9 FF FC 97 9F 40 F6 29 10 82 A3 EF 73 0E C5 79 B0 6E 9A 80  ñÏ¯ÿéÿü@ö).£ïs.Åy°n
F8 FC F9 F3 B6 38 0E 00 8E 4F C1 4E 39 20 9D CC E4 EE BB F0 61 1C 02 10  øüùó¶8..OÁN9 Ìäî»ða...
5D 9B E7 2B 0E 45 D7 3F 3C 08 31 1C 01 0C 43 13 EE 39 08 5F 33 F7 28 3E  ]ç+.E×?<.1...C.î9._3÷(>
15 C7 00 C4 C0 15 45 66 37 61 5C 98 10 56 9B 58 7A 73 37 B9 B7 B9 10 CC  .Ç.ÄÀ.Ef7a\.VXzs7¹·¹.Ì
09 7A 2B C1 FB FB E5 26 98 E1 26 90 AB F8 E2 EC 74 25 04 72 8A 3E DA F8  .z+Áûûå&á&«øâìt%.r>Úø
6E C0 F1 C8 CB 60 84 28 5A BF 83 E7 F1 CD 65 E3 F8 83 38 20 7D 23 7D 29  nÀñÈË`(Z¿çñÍeãø8 }#})
AD 16 41 41 9F C5 A5 DF EB E4 1F 88 1D 5B 03 81 A1 F4 2C 33 2E B7 1C 92  ­.AAÅ¥ßëä..[.¡ô,3.·.
78 74 C7 72 20 49 28 A5 40 46 73 13 F8 70 DA B5 0B F9 9B 41 A1 F4 D6 2F  xtÇr I(¥@Fs.øpÚµ.ùA¡ôÖ/
38 0C D7 73 B3 90 42 40 81 74 64 58 08 37 3E BE 8E 62 29 45 91 84 D2 E4  8.×s³B@tdX.7>¾b)EÒä
64 2C 6C E6 0C 7B CB 9A B9 F8 5C A0 60 DA 37 8F 8E BD DB 06 26 9F 3A F1  d,læ.{Ë¹ø\ `Ú7½Û.&:ñ
D3 48 C2 68 7A 3C AD CB C0 D3 78 0A 36 9F 58 29 14 18 48 07 A6 0C 8E FD  ÓHÂhz<­ËÀÓx.6X)..H.¦.ý
64 07 36 78 69 3C 6F A3 48 0A 92 9F 61 3C 3D F9 4C 0A 82 06 D2 BA 54 30  d.6xi<o£H.a<=ùL..ÒºT0
B8 09 3D A7 83 DF 08 98 18 F5 CB 20 0D 1E 6D 18 4D AF 5C 18 B3 97 5C 95  ¸.=§ß..õË ..m.M¯\.³\
B9 AE FF 2A 29 14 18 4F 7B 2E 9F F2 50 AC 0E 92 24 A2 26 0F C5 14 73 16  ¹®ÿ*)..O{.òP¬.$¢&.Å.s.
C9 4D FC 35 58 69 7E DA 4E E2 2A 05 72 E3 97 06 84 B4 91 CB EE 9D 38 B8  ÉMü5Xi~ÚNâ*.rã.´Ëî8¸
B6 51 9E DA 0D CE B0 5F CF 68 E1 8A B9 14 45 12 5B 93 10 5F E6 6E C2 46  ¶QÚ.Î°_Ïhá¹.E.[._ænÂF
92 D1 83 35 41 FC 38 50 92 3A 74 93 B9 B1 19 0B C4 97 C5 DC CA 3F 61 18  Ñ5Aü8P:t¹±..ÄÅÜÊ?a.
5D 2F 4B FE B3 51 02 B2 8F C2 EB A8 B0 8F 96 4F 11 BD 9F DA 7C EE EF EE  ]/Kþ³Q.²Âë¨°O.½Ú|îïî
A4 58 60 94 FD 62 F2 09 FB 54 F4 B0 24 31 96 46 93 32 14 EC FB B9 37 B3  ¤X`ýbò.ûTô°$1F2.ìû¹7³
99 F4 C4 EE C3 F0 8A AA 19 1D 18 30 B6 0E 6C 91 DE 7E FA A1 64 1F E5 AC  ôÄîÃðª...0¶.lÞ~ú¡d.å¬
7D 5F CE 32 43 CA AA AA ED 40 B0 C4 33 1D 93 24 2F 85 83 E2 EB 46 2E F6  }_Î2CÊªªí@°Ä3.$/âëF.ö
6E 1E FD 34 15 97 DF FB 30 C6 5E D9 2C E3 6F 3F 15 1C 28 C4 C6 6C 2D E7  n.ý4.ßû0Æ^Ù,ão?..(ÄÆl-ç
93 C6 51 8C C1 E5 6C 9E DB E5 52 9A 3B EE C3 28 7B 1B 62 D5 59 14 FC C1  ÆQÁålÛåR;îÃ({.bÕY.üÁ
D5 03 74 90 44 DB E4 35 05 B7 E4 7B 8A 31 4B 59 4E E3 CB 94 42 81 C1 F6  Õ.tDÛä5.·ä{1KYNãËBÁö
C6 CE 5C CE 3E 99 6B 67 43 10 67 6E 07 28 D4 F6 6D 3C 33 6C AB E4 DA 4E  ÆÎ\Î>kgC.gn.(Ôöm<3l«äÚN
EE A5 28 60 A8 ED 9B 27 F6 1E D4 00 81 DA 02 97 7E 0E BA 9B 4A EF 84 06  î¥(`¨í'ö.Ô.Ú.~.ºJï.
DA 34 99 0E 7C 56 70 1D 5F 9A 97 3F 10 D8 1E B8 35 C1 CC 11 10 71 DF E8  Ú4.|Vp._?.Ø.¸5ÁÌ..qßè
00 F5 07 7A C1 B8 19 07 E3 6B 88 61 24 4C A5 38 1A 34 08 50 FF 4A 09 49  .õ.zÁ¸..ãka$L¥8.4.PÿJ.I
12 5B E9 51 B5 01 A4 26 85 79 78 B0 3F B3 28 C1 3C 00 C6 D4 6E 3C AA 53  .[éQµ.¤&yx°?³(Á<.ÆÔn<ªS
3E C4 2B 41 49 62 6A F2 4C 7E 26 A6 EF E2 08 F1 FF 92 86 F6 43 D8 1F 18  >Ä+AIbjòL~&¦ïâ.ñÿöCØ..
38 F8 40 54 80 C0 98 FA 79 69 C6 7C C1 F5 C5 66 F2 E6 C0 A1 B0 DD FA C5  8ø@TÀúyiÆ|ÁõÅfòæÀ¡°ÝúÅ
89 23 D9 21 6C 0B F4 E6 6E 6F C0 A6 46 1A 30 50 CA 7A 6E 7D 98 F1 28 56  #Ù!l.ôænoÀ¦F.0PÊzn}ñ(V
D2 DE E2 21 8A A6 DD 50 F2 49 73 67 32 29 E3 5F 24 C5 81 B2 D5 EA BA E5  ÒÞâ!¦ÝPòIsg2)ã_$Å²Õêºå
60 0C FD 32 B3 D2 A4 F0 50 DC 0B 50 81 71 04 E3 E8 9F 3E 16 52 34 6E C4  `.ý2³Ò¤ðPÜ.Pq.ãè>.R4nÄ
02 D4 2D 97 86 02 0A 72 3C 28 98 0E 0C B8 60 22 8A 99 78 52 73 84 B2 D3  .Ô-..r<(..¸`"xRs²Ó
B3 A7 E7 64 FC 3D 18 E5 62 EC 9F C4 29 C8 11 DA 02 68 D0 BD 52 09 A6 47  ³§çdü=.åbìÄ)È.Ú.hÐ½R.¦G
38 49 5D DA 07 92 93 75 CA 59 B9 2C 76 70 4A 50 47 60 60 D9 40 32 B4 33  8I]Ú.uÊY¹,vpJPG``Ù@2´3
2B 0D 67 47 30 49 BD 2C 33 BE E8 55 99 52 1C C1 26 C0 6D 30 13 CB 7F 33  +.gG0I½,3¾èUR.Á&Àm0.Ë3
26 CB C4 33 9B 23 14 57 7F CC 0E 39 1C 83 95 9D C6 7A 4A FE D5 C0 E0 DA  &ËÄ3#.WÌ.9.ÆzJþÕÀàÚ
AB 1E 3D 3F 51 53 C2 72 8C 7A AD EB 51 C8 CE DF CE 31 0A AC 7F B8 7C 62  «.=?QSÂrz­ëQÈÎßÎ1.¬¸|b
73 FE F5 88 3F 9A 63 98 A4 56 AD 22 FE BD C8 41 C0 04 15 AC 47 A8 5B 7B  sþõ?c¤V­"þ½ÈAÀ..¬G¨[{
22 63 69 64 22 3A 32 2C 22 63 5F 50 72 65 66 69 78 31 22 3A 22 4D 72 73  "cid":2,"c_Prefix1":"Mrs
2E 22 2C 22 63 5F 66 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 50 61 74 74 69 22 2C 22 63  .","c_fName1":"Patti","c
5F 6D 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 22 2C 22 63 5F 6C 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22  _mName1":"","c_lName1":"
4C 69 67 68 74 6E 65 72 22 2C 22 63 5F 53 75 66 66 69 78 31 22 3A 22 22  Lightner","c_Suffix1":""
2C 22 63 5F 52 65 6E 77 65 62 50 65 72 73 6F 6E 49 44 22 3A 6E 75 6C 6C  ,"c_RenwebPersonID":null
2C 22 67 65 6E 64 65 72 22 3A 6E 75 6C 6C 7D 2C 7B 22 63 69 64 22 3A 33  ,"gender":null},{"cid":3
2C 22 63 5F 50 72 65 66 69 78 31 22 3A 22 4D 72 2E 22 2C 22 63 5F 66 4E  ,"c_Prefix1":"Mr.","c_fN
61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 44 6F 6E 22 2C 22 63 5F 6D 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22  ame1":"Don","c_mName1":"
22 2C 22 63 5F 6C 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 47 72 65 69 64 65 72 22 2C 22  ","c_lName1":"Greider","
63 5F 53 75 66 66 69 78 31 22 3A 22 49 49 49 22 2C 22 63 5F 52 65 6E 77  c_Suffix1":"III","c_Renw
65 62 50 65 72 73 6F 6E 49 44 22 3A 6E 75 6C 6C 2C 22 67 65 6E 64 65 72  ebPersonID":null,"gender
22 3A 6E 75 6C 6C 7D 2C 7B 22 63 69 64 22 3A 34 2C 22 63 5F 50 72 65 66  ":null},{"cid":4,"c_Pref
69 78 31 22 3A 22 4D 72 2E 22 2C 22 63 5F 66 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 46  ix1":"Mr.","c_fName1":"F
72 65 64 22 2C 22 63 5F 6D 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 22 2C 22 63 5F 6C 4E  red","c_mName1":"","c_lN
61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 41 6C 61 6E 69 7A 22 2C 22 63 5F 53 75 66 66 69 78  ame1":"Alaniz","c_Suffix
31 22 3A 22 22 2C 22 63 5F 52 65 6E 77 65 62 50 65 72 73 6F 6E 49 44 22  1":"","c_RenwebPersonID"
3A 6E 75 6C 6C 2C 22 67 65 6E 64 65 72 22 3A 6E 75 6C 6C 7D 2C 7B 22 63  :null,"gender":null},{"c
69 64 22 3A 35 2C 22 63 5F 50 72 65 66 69 78 31 22 3A 22 4D 72 2E 22 2C  id":5,"c_Prefix1":"Mr.",
22 63 5F 66 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 42 65 6E 6E 79 22 2C 22 63 5F 6D 4E  "c_fName1":"Benny","c_mN
61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 22 2C 22 63 5F 6C 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 42 6F 70  ame1":"","c_lName1":"Bop
70 22 2C 22 63 5F 53 75 66 66 69 78 31 22 3A 22 22 2C 22 63 5F 52 65 6E  p","c_Suffix1":"","c_Ren
77 65 62 50 65 72 73 6F 6E 49 44 22 3A 6E 75 6C 6C 2C 22 67 65 6E 64 65  webPersonID":null,"gende
72 22 3A 6E 75 6C 6C 7D 2C 7B 22 63 69 64 22 3A 36 2C 22 63 5F 50 72 65  r":null},{"cid":6,"c_Pre
66 69 78 31 22 3A 22 4D 72 2E 22 2C 22 63 5F 66 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22  fix1":"Mr.","c_fName1":"
4D 61 72 6B 22 2C 22 63 5F 6D 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 22 2C 22 63 5F 6C  Mark","c_mName1":"","c_l
4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 4F 6C 69 76 65 72 22 2C 22 63 5F 53 75 66 66 69  Name1":"Oliver","c_Suffi
78 31 22 3A 22 22 2C 22 63 5F 52 65 6E 77 65 62 50 65 72 73 6F 6E 49 44  x1":"","c_RenwebPersonID
22 3A 6E 75 6C 6C 2C 22 67 65 6E 64 65 72 22 3A 6E 75 6C 6C 7D 2C 7B 22  ":null,"gender":null},{"
63 69 64 22 3A 37 2C 22 63 5F 50 72 65 66 69 78 31 22 3A 22 4D 72 2E 22  cid":7,"c_Prefix1":"Mr."
2C 22 63 5F 66 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 4C 69 74 74 6C 65 22 2C 22 63 5F  ,"c_fName1":"Little","c_
6D 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 48 61 72 72 79 22 2C 22 63 5F 6C 4E 61 6D 65  mName1":"Harry","c_lName
31 22 3A 22 43 68 69 63 6B 65 6E 22 2C 22 63 5F 53 75 66 66 69 78 31 22  1":"Chicken","c_Suffix1"
3A 22 22 2C 22 63 5F 52 65 6E 77 65 62 50 65 72 73 6F 6E 49 44 22 3A 6E  :"","c_RenwebPersonID":n
75 6C 6C 2C 22 67 65 6E 64 65 72 22 3A 6E 75 6C 6C 7D 2C 7B 22 63 69 64  ull,"gender":null},{"cid
22 3A 38 2C 22 63 5F 50 72 65 66 69 78 31 22 3A 22 4D 72 2E 22 2C 22 63  ":8,"c_Prefix1":"Mr.","c
5F 66 4E 61 6D 65 31 22 3A 22 42 72 6F 6F 6B 73 22 2C 22 63 5F 6D 4E 61  _fName1":"Brooks","c_mNa
6D 65 31 22 3A 22 4D 22                                                  me1":"M"
```

So I caught it in wireshark and got the following:

```
0000   45 00 03 be 5a 3e 40 00 80 06 00 00 7f 00 00 01  E...Z>@.........
0010   7f 00 00 01 00 50 15 41 a9 38 d2 03 53 c8 0f 17  .....P.A.8..S...
0020   50 18 00 fd e0 2f 00 00 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31  P..../..HTTP/1.1
0030   20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0d 0a 43 61 63 68 65 2d 43   200 OK..Cache-C
0040   6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20 6e 6f 2d 63 61 63 68 65  ontrol: no-cache
0050   0d 0a 50 72 61 67 6d 61 3a 20 6e 6f 2d 63 61 63  ..Pragma: no-cac
0060   68 65 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 65  he..Content-Type
0070   3a 20 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 6a 73  : application/js
0080   6f 6e 3b 20 63 68 61 72 73 65 74 3d 75 74 66 2d  on; charset=utf-
0090   38 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 45 6e 63 6f 64  8..Content-Encod
00a0   69 6e 67 3a 20 67 7a 69 70 0d 0a 45 78 70 69 72  ing: gzip..Expir
00b0   65 73 3a 20 2d 31 0d 0a 53 65 72 76 65 72 3a 20  es: -1..Server: 
00c0   4d 69 63 72 6f 73 6f 66 74 2d 49 49 53 2f 31 30  Microsoft-IIS/10
00d0   2e 30 0d 0a 58 2d 41 73 70 4e 65 74 2d 56 65 72  .0..X-AspNet-Ver
00e0   73 69 6f 6e 3a 20 34 2e 30 2e 33 30 33 31 39 0d  sion: 4.0.30319.
00f0   0a 58 2d 50 6f 77 65 72 65 64 2d 42 79 3a 20 41  .X-Powered-By: A
0100   53 50 2e 4e 45 54 0d 0a 44 61 74 65 3a 20 54 75  SP.NET..Date: Tu
0110   65 2c 20 30 33 20 4e 6f 76 20 32 30 31 35 20 31  e, 03 Nov 2015 1
0120   39 3a 32 35 3a 34 32 20 47 4d 54 0d 0a 43 6f 6e  9:25:42 GMT..Con
0130   74 65 6e 74 2d 4c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20 36 33 34  tent-Length: 634
0140   0d 0a 0d 0a 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 ed 95  ................
0150   6d 6f d3 30 10 c7 bf 4a e5 57 80 ba aa e9 d8 aa  mo.0...J.W......
0160   ee d5 3a ca 78 10 63 d3 56 10 12 42 d5 61 5f 1a  ..:.x.c.V..B.a_.
0170   ab 8e 5d d9 0e 5b 41 7c 77 2e 8f 4d 1f 50 27 84  ..]..[A|w..M.P'.
0180   aa 6a ca 8b b4 f1 dd e5 ee 7f 67 ff e4 af bf d8  .j........g.....
0190   1c ad 33 fa dd 88 9d 05 dd 41 d0 6f 33 05 ce 7f  ..3......A.o3...
01a0   84 18 d9 19 7b 0b 7c 86 de b3 36 0b a5 ad ac 63  ....{.|...6....c
01b0   a9 81 4c b1 14 42 61 61 a3 b5 03 95 78 f0 d2 68  ..L..Baa....x..h
01c0   5a 5f 59 d7 49 6d 49 18 ca 87 dc af 25 9f 2d a3  Z_Y.ImI.....%.-.
01d0   a7 a8 05 da fc fd bb b4 3e 12 e0 c9 a5 13 a5 da  ........>.......
01e0   0c 63 90 8a 7c 9e 2a 45 a4 e1 9c 9b 98 93 ac 8e  .c..|.*E........
01f0   c6 54 4c e6 ee e5 df 82 10 16 9d 4b f5 77 db 2c  .TL........K.w.,
0200   32 31 de 44 46 a7 45 9e 4d 26 93 e7 f4 1c d1 33  21.DF.E.M&.....3
0210   a1 48 8e 4a fd cd 77 6f ec ac f4 d1 d2 70 9e cc  .H.J..wo.....p..
0220   cb 56 c6 08 3c 22 a9 94 c1 c4 73 d0 8b 52 65 08  .V..<"....s..Re.
0230   0f e5 eb d4 82 48 b2 0f 46 b5 36 52 2b 7e c0 1f  .....H..F.6R+~..
0240   a8 4a 0b 4f 9c 37 82 32 84 a0 1c a6 19 2d a9 9f  .J.O.7.2.....-..
0250   1b 9a 85 e6 58 99 a5 f6 48 76 4f d5 2f 8d 8d d1  ....X...HvO./...
0260   b6 ee 3c 84 21 49 b0 a8 b2 32 2e 92 f3 32 69 31  ..<.!I...2...2i1
0270   82 60 6d dd ab 8a 4a 5f 69 76 be a6 ef e7 32 07  .`m...J_iv....2.
0280   37 89 f6 b6 16 96 90 22 9f 4e f5 28 20 3d 6e 84  7......".N.( =n.
0290   1c c1 a1 58 4a 74 af 12 d2 ae fd 0d a4 bf 35 fb  ...XJt........5.
02a0   50 25 b1 96 1b e6 bc 91 0d 73 91 e5 8d 05 2d e6  P%.......s....-.
02b0   db 53 6d f7 e5 f9 b6 fb 8a a4 77 79 17 1b 09 37  .Sm.......wy...7
02c0   b2 6c 06 56 19 d2 b1 6f 86 af 5a 29 f8 da d3 11  .l.V...o..Z)....
02d0   b9 84 58 aa 45 3d 5c c1 d4 55 eb 08 5c 51 e8 16  ..X.E=\..U..\Q..
02e0   69 e3 97 b3 0c a5 42 31 74 e5 f0 a5 bb d6 6a 51  i.....B1t.....jQ
02f0   69 f2 36 c1 df ed 15 50 83 e3 d3 e3 15 50 87 3c  i.6....P.....P.<
0300   db 40 d0 ff 9d d5 e2 24 3f 86 d6 bd 93 79 91 38  .@.....$?....y.8
0310   a9 a9 44 eb 0a 34 4c 1b 44 1b 44 0f 09 d1 c1 ea  ..D..4L.D.D.....
0320   5d fa e2 93 cb 4e 68 9d ce cf 12 ef 77 d1 b9 57  ]....Nh.....w..W
0330   32 d7 60 dc c1 5f c3 5b c3 db c1 f0 76 12 9c ae  2.`.._.[....v...
0340   f0 76 91 ca 55 6a 8d b8 91 d1 a0 c4 2e e6 46 f6  .v..Uj........F.
0350   d1 17 e2 15 28 fc 37 f4 fa fd 93 c1 53 a7 8f 05  ....(.7.....S...
0360   dd a0 f5 ba d3 ba 45 1d 5a 43 1f b1 3a 8b 59 0b  ......E.ZC..:.Y.
0370   19 89 e9 6e 29 a4 bd 6c b1 0a 48 36 fe c2 0a 20  ...n)..l..H6... 
0380   f3 5e 0b 1c b3 dd 6a 60 3c 6c 18 7b 2f d7 60 54  .^....j`<l.{/.`T
0390   53 2b f5 1a 8c ef e9 cf ed e3 fe 9b 5a 3a 3c c2  S+..........Z:<.
03a0   cd 10 49 e4 b9 e3 91 31 aa 43 f0 34 f7 62 73 2f  ..I....1.C.4.bs/
03b0   3e 39 14 bf fd 01 54 b7 34 54 d5 11 00 00        >9....T.4T....
```

But the headers all look okay to me. Wireshark does have a tcp packet after this that has [RST, ACK] and is colored red, but I guess that is because this connection was broken?

Solutions in other SO answers and around the web do not apply or do not help: useUnsafeHeaderParsing is set to true, caching is disabled, patch/continue/notmodified etc are not being returned just 200 ok, CRLFCRLF looks fine, UserAgent is not null.

I have no idea what is going on. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Seem CRLF have some problem -> Carriage Return and Line Feed.
Try to use chr(13)+chr(10) at the end

Comment: from the hexdump `0140   0d 0a 0d 0a` you'll see `chr(13)+chr(10)` is present twice

Comment: What is your language environment? Sometime it interpret with wrong encode language set.

Comment: en-US. Isn't it in utf8 anyway?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641786/illegal-304-http-response

Comment: as noted above, caching is already disabled

Comment: So I am not sure, But I think you are using different encoding/character set with api server. or the header with something wrong. try this:
http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/11/http11-webrequest-with-expect-100.html

Comment: Seem header in UTF8 but response json in en-US encoding

Comment: Not a solution but I tracked it down to disappearing when I disabled a CompressionHandler that seems to have come from [this tutorial](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-web-api-compression). I'm not sure if it's a larger issue that may still happen when there are concurrent requests or something, but this load off makes it not happen anymore.